# Python Eve document versioning not store all fileds into resource_version document unless i declare the fields in schema,I

Tags: python, eve

I did define all schema in domain because the dynamic fields will create as business require

So I enable document versioning and I find only eve fields strore in shadow document, other fields not store in.

Is possibl to make all fields store into version document when I enable allow unknown setting because I  enable allow_unknown setting to let client receive all fields